# Two types of URLs in codeigniter. One for pagination and one for showing the item - how to?

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo, pagination

I have some codeigniter gallery app with my own search engine etc.

On the single item page there are **next** and **previous** buttons to navigate between images.

My image url looks like:

```
myurl.com/image/keyword/res_position
```

**keyword** variable is obvious the keyword which user typed for search, and **res_position** is the position in results listing - I need it to navigate between next and previous.

Ofc my next item has url

```
myurl.com/keyword/res_position+1
```

and previous

```
myurl.com/keyword/res_position-1
```

That's it. Works like a charm.

My problem is that I want to have some method that could be used only to show single image. I thought about

```
mysite.com/image/id
```

and that will do the job - but I'm worried about duplicate content and SEO aspect.

As you can see, my "next-previous" URL structure has a lot of variations, because user can type a lot of other keywords, and single image "res-position" can be a different number every time.

Can you recommend me some soultions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought -

Providing multiple URI's for the same content is gonna cause duplicate problem but I don't think you can do much about this. However, you can try disallowing certain URLs from searching engines using `robots.txt` - this should help you stop duplicate content problem...

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /image/something
```

**UPDATE**

> Robots.txt is also used to avoid what is known as “canonicalization”
>   problems or having multiple “canonical” URLs. This problem is
>   sometimes referred to incorrectly as a “duplicate content” problem.
>
> Canonicalization problems occur where multiple pages on a website
>   contain the same information. For example, a product page might also
>   have a “Print” version to make it easier to print out the specs and
>   details on the product. This can pose a problem to search engines who
>   then have to figure out which version of the page (i.e.
>   site.com/product-a.html or site.com/product-a-print.html) is the
>   canonical one. Robots.txt would be used to keep the secondary
>   version(s) from being indexed.

Reference : http://seoroi.com/seo-faq/robotstxt-what-it-is-why-its-used-and-how-to-write-it/

Comment: Thank you! : ) and I don't need to edit my url structure for 4789237582389 time now! : )